# How to search in sqlite for hour regardless of timezone?

Tags: sqlite, timestamp, timezone

I wanted to make a database containing my blood sugar levels (I have diabetes). 
For each entry, the timestamp of the measurement is saved like this "2020-05-02 12:11:13 +0200".

Now I want to plot the data by the hour (get the same hour of different days).

If I have traveled to a different timezone the entries for this day will be n hours of.
For example, if I want to get all entries for 13:00 I will get the values that were measured at 04:00 in California and 20:00 in Tokyo. But I want the 13:00 o'Clock values from all these places/timezones.

Is this possible, or should I just create a separate column for UTC and local time?

I already tried things like these:

```
... WHERE strftime('%H', date) = '13'
... WHERE strftime('%H', date,"UTC") = '13'
... WHERE time(date)>= time('00:00:00','+13 hour')
```

**Solution:**
See @forpas answer.

I modified it a little

```
strftime('%H',datetime( substr(date, 1, 19))) = '10'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need string functions to extract the `YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss` part of the date and add the offset which may include minutes:

```
where 
  strftime(
    '%H', 
    datetime(
      substr(date, 1, 19), 
      substr(date, 21, 3) || ' hour',
      substr(date, 21, 1) || substr(date, -2) || ' minute'
    )  
  ) = '13'
```

Answer (score 0):

apparently sqlite doesn't understand the format of your timestamp, because of the timezone format at the end (`+0200`)

not sure if you must use da date/time function, but you can easily subtract the hour with substr;

```
 ... WHERE substr(tm, 12, 2) = '13'
```